# Can someone explain me the difference between both this if conditions in React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

```
state = {
    count: 1,
  };
    
render() {
    let classes = "badge m-5 bg-";
    let { count } = this.state;

    count === 1 ? (classes += "success") : (classes += "warning");//1st Condition
    classes+= (count===1)?"success" : "warning";//2nd Condition
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <span style={this.styles} className={classes} id="bad">
          Hello!
        </span>
       </div>
    );
  }
```

I understood how that if condition works(`condition ? true: false`), but in the 2nd condition how it is possibly working even after placing the `classes+=` even before mentioning the condition?

Comment: In simple form Your second if condition is `classes = classes  + (count===1 ? "success":"danger")
`

Comment: Both are doing the same thing, comparing the count to 1, in case it is true appending `success` to classes otherwise it appends `warning`

Comment: @GulamHussain that's really basic, but I forgot, feel guilty.lol

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate a bit more? The question is not clear to me. What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: @Maverick  it has to simply append the strings "success" or "warning" in to the classes variable according to the value stored in state.count obj and then changes the bg-color of the badge/span, and it is exactly working(both the condition gives the same o/p) but I was bit confused with the 2nd condition.

Comment: Yeah, I think you have it sorted out. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down. Remember, our initial value of count is 1.

```
let classes = "badge m-5 bg-";
...
classes+= (count===1)?"success" : "warning";
```

Firstly what'll happen is that `count===1` will be checked for strict equality (it takes precedence), which will yield `true`. Since our condition is true, and we're using ternary operator, the expression returns `"success"` string, i.e.,

this:

```
classes+= (count===1)?"success" : "warning";
```

becomes this:

```
classes+= "success";
```

`"success"` will be appended to the `classes` string, therefore `classes` will become `badge m-5 bg-success`

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd Condition, tt related to [javascript operator precedence](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/javascript-operator-precedencea). `?:` before `+=`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, ternary operator (`?...:`) takes precedence over assignment (`+=`), so the right hand of the `+=` resolves first and append either "success" or "warning" to `classes`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table